# Toasts are shown not simultaneously

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a part of code in which I firstly `setText`, then make a `Toast` and after that I'm trying to connect via Bluetooth. The problem is that my `setText` and `Toasts` appear only after connection has been made.

I tried to put `Log.i` instead of `Toasts` and they were shown simultaneously.

Can somebody explain me why and how to make `Toasts` simultaneously?

Code:

```
........

else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {      
    tvDevices.setText("");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    connect(btDevice, ConstantsVariables.reconnectionAttempts);
}

public void connect(BluetoothDevice bt, int attempts){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trying to connect...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(attempts > 0){
        for(int i = 1; i <= ConstantsVariables.reconnectionAttempts; i++){
            ConnectThread thread = new ConnectThread(bt);
            boolean connectVar = thread.connect();
            if(connectVar){
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
}

.......

public boolean connect() {
    BA.cancelDiscovery();
    try {
        mSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CONNECTTHREAD","Could not connect: " + e.toString());
        try {
            mSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException exception){}
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're blocking the UI Thread while connection is being attempted. Try to move the connection code to a background thread, or an AsyncTask, and handle the UI Changes in the AsyncTask's callbacks.

Edit: Also the context `getApplicationContext()` passed to Toast is ambiguous. Are you in an activity? In that case it should simply point to the Activity's context i.e. `this` and not the Application's context

Comment: Ok, I understood about `getApplicationContext()`. But can you explain, please, about background thread and how to make it?

Comment: I understood that I should make a construction like `AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {}
});` but where to put it and what to put inside? Thanks!

Comment: You can either use an AsyncTask or a Background thread with Handler, not both together. The simplest example on how to use either is here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#example